# 2.5 MB .js file too big? Can't load variables from file

Tags: javascript, arrays, file

I have a 2.5 MB .js file with 11,000 arrays each 20-30 in length. I am unable to load these arrays when I call the file. I have cut the file to 500 arrays and the code works just fine, so I am calling the file and the variables correctly. I have also wrapped the variable call in a try catch block to see if it is just loading very slow, but is goes straight to the catch block.

In HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="call.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.js"></script>
```

In call.js:

```
try {
  document.getElementById("btn1").innerHTML = list1[2];
} catch {
  document.getElementById("btn1").innerHTML = "no";
}
```

In data.js:

```
list1 = ["200", "300", ... , "2700"]
...
list11000 = ["200", "300", ... , "2700"]
```

Comment: What error is being caught? Have you tried ``catch(err) { console.log(err.message); }``

Comment: my bad forgot to include that, it's "list1 is no defined" error.

Comment: You need to load ``data.js`` before ``call.js``. So swap the order of your two ``<script>`` tags. As it is, ``call.js`` is attempting to reference an array that has not yet been loaded in ``data.js``.

Comment: Okay I did this and received a new error now "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -" in data.js. What does this mean

Comment: It sounds like you have a syntax error in ``data.js``. Please show us the contents of the line number that contains that character.

Comment: Okay my bad I found the problem. I was calling 11283 arrays but the file only held 11282. I got it to work now.